# Embed NoSQL document/EAV database in desktop program, like SQLite3, but NoSQL?

Tags: c++, sqlite, nosql, entity-attribute-value, client-applications

What's the best choice if I want to embed a document db or EAV db in client application?

Something like "SQLite3 for NoSQL", small runtime library, index arbitary schema, small memory footprint, etc. C/C++ API or ActiveX/COM interface would be awesome!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some development, I have to say, the best options so far are LevelDB and Tokyo Cabinet.